# Dell cable M246M vs generic mini sas cable

Tags: sas, dell-perc, cable

Is there any difference beyond brand between a Dell M246M cable and a generic mini sas-8087 cable? Is it just branding, quality control? Or is there some difference in the actual cables or connectors?

Eg this [dell M246M cable](http://www.ebay.com/itm/M246M-0M246M-DELL-POWEREDGE-R610-R710-H700-SAS-A-SAS-B-SATA-CABLE-/351040137213?hash=item51bb9f67fd:g:lq0AAOSw-zxWnWGm) is the cheapest I could find on eBay at the time of writing: US$18, whereas it looks like [this Mini SAS cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00S6ATQ1U) on amazon is closer to US$9 (you can find similar on eBay down to US$7)

(I will be using these for hooking up H700 raid cards in Dell R610's.)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference.

SAS-8087 connecters are built to a standard. Ideally, you'd just buy the Dell cable. The cost isn't high, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks! So the difference if any is in the quality of the cable, right? Thanks...